# Managing private keys used to sign server-side transactions in decentralized apps

Tags: security, private-key

What are the best practices for managing private keys used to sign server-side transactions in decentralized apps?

Currently, we're testing a dapp with the private key exposed as an environment variable on the server. We want to do better than that.

Answer (score 0):

A good approach would be to create multiple points of failure and only create it at runtime. To start with, you can divide your key in 4 parts, store each part in a different keystore (you can use AWS, Microsoft etc.) and only merge them at runtime.